# Combining js files efficiently

Tags: javascript

So, I have my main `custom_js.js` as shown below:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
    $(function () {     
        'use strict';   
             //js goes here

        // Default line End
    }); 
})(jQuery, this);
```

Now, I have an external [js file](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dinbror/blazy/master/blazy.min.js) from blazy lazy load.

I tried to put the code in my custom_js.js as below (by just copying and pasting)

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
    $(function () {     
        'use strict';   
        //blazy v.1.5.1         
            (function(k,f){"function"===typeof.....
        // Default line End
    }); 
})(jQuery, this);
```

But I am getting an error (that "blazy" was not found).

I am simply trying to consolidate the external js into my custom_js file.

What am I doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

**This is the setup:(Everything in footer)**

Using the external js.

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/dinbror/blazy/master/blazy.min.js"></script>

  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/js/custom_js.js"></script>
```

Comment: Can you post you html header where you embed these 2 JS?

Comment: I've just seen your EDIT. Why are you doing both including `blazy.min.js` AND copy & pasting it into your own `custom_js.js`? Just including `blazy.min.js` is enough.

Comment: I am trying to remove the external js and put into my own custom. The edit part is before consolidating. Anyway, I got it working =)

Comment: Where did you get error? On the line where you pasted `blazy` code in your `custom_js.js` or where you are trying to use `blazy`?

Comment: I moved the external code outside of my code in the `custom_js.js` (See the accepted answer). it works now =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about pasting it at the end of `custom_js.js` like that:

```
(function ($, root, undefined) {    
    $(function () {     
        'use strict';   
             //js goes here

        // Default line End
    }); 
})(jQuery, this);

//blazy v.1.5.1         
(function(k,f){"function"===typeof.....
```

Comment: i will give that a try =)

Comment: Yup that did it.  =) haha, simple solution always works the best! Thanks man